# Objective-C FTP Uploading and Downloading files

Tags: objective-c, upload, download

I'm looking to download a file from an FTP server as well as upload a file to an FTP server with Objective-C. Don't point me out to ConnectionKit, iPhone resources, or integration of Applescript code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want horrible integration of this you can use an NSTask to use with wget or ftp.